# XSLT Should Process Nodes With Same Date Only Once

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for XSLT to sum quantities with same date only once when traversing through the xml file.

Input:

```
<root>
  <interval>
    <mn>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-14</date>
        <ccode>102010</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-15</date>
        <ccode>202010</ccode>
    </mn>
  </interval>
  <interval>
    <mn>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-15</date>
        <ccode>202000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-17</date>
        <ccode>302010</ccode>
    </mn>
  </interval>
  <interval>
    <mn>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-14</date>
        <ccode>102000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-18</date>
        <ccode>402010</ccode>
    </mn>
  </interval>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
    <mn>
        <quantity>6</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-14</date>
        <ccode>102000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-15</date>
        <ccode>202000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-17</date>
        <ccode>302010</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-18</date>
        <ccode>402010</ccode>
    </mn>
```

The quantities are added when date matches. Problem with my xslt is it traverses every mn node in first interval node, sums up quantities for same date from all interval nodes, then it traverses second interval and sums up quantities "again from all interval nodes". I want the sum of quantities for one date only once. CCODE value should be the least/minimum of all the values for a date.
My XSLT is as below:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="root/interval/mn">      
    <xsl:variable name="dtt" select="date"/>      
        <xsl:variable name="qty" select="sum(../../interval/mn[date = $dtt]/quantity)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @MarkVeenstra XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most of the way there - just need to use Muenchian grouping (define an `xsl:key`) have your `for-each` select each date node only once.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="mnByDate" match="mn" use="date" />
    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <root> 
            <xsl:for-each select="root/interval/mn[count(. | key('mnByDate', date)[1]) = 1]">      
                <xsl:variable name="dtt" select="date"/>      
                <xsl:variable name="ccode" select="ccode"/>      
                <xsl:variable name="qty" select="sum(../../interval/mn[date = $dtt]/quantity)"/>
                <mn>
                    <quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$qty"/>
                    </quantity>
                    <date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$dtt" />
                    </date>
                    <ccode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//mn[date = $dtt]/ccode[not(. > //mn[date = $dtt]/ccode)][1]" />
                    </ccode>
                </mn>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <mn>
        <quantity>6</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-14</date>
        <ccode>102000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-15</date>
        <ccode>202000</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-17</date>
        <ccode>302010</ccode>
    </mn>
    <mn>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <date>2015-03-18</date>
        <ccode>402010</ccode>
    </mn>
</root>
```

Comment: Superb marvelous. It is working. Thanks. But I ran into another problem. There is more data in the mn tag. I will try to update my question.

Comment: ccode for 2015-03-14 and 2015-03-15 look incorrect in the output. Is this because of greater than sign you have put?

Comment: Was too hasty there - redid the xpath expression so it actually works now.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the kind help. It is working now. Can you explain me the meaning of 2 lines you have added in simple words. I am not too familiar with xslt. select="root/interval/mn[count(. | key('mnByDate', date)[1]) = 1]" select="//mn[date = $dtt]/ccode[not(. > //mn[date = $dtt]/ccode)][1]"

Comment: The first one is for Meunchian grouping - search for here or on Google for more info.  The second says "the first ccode node whose sibling date is = $dtt and isn't greater than any other ccode with the same date"